# with efficacy rates and trials delaying official take-up

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "with efficacy rates and trials delaying official take-up" mean "because of its efficacy rates and trials that had delayed the official take-up (what does "take-up" mean here? Cambridge Dictionary defines it as "how much people start to use or accept a service, or sometimes a product, that has become available to them" and I don't know how to match it to the context.

> New Scientist tweeted 21m ago:

> Oxford University/AstraZeneca vaccine criticised by US regulator the Food and Drug Administration, **with efficacy rates and trials delaying official take-up**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is mostly correct, with some problems of tense ("had delayed" is wrong, because it still **is** delayed in the US). Let me rewrite it to clarify:

- The FDA (a US regulator) is criticising the OU/AZ vaccine. [Lower than expected] efficacy rates and [the need for more] trials are delaying the official adoption of the vaccine in the US.

*Official take-up* just means that the vaccine officially starts being used, as you say. We have heard the horrible word 'rollout' in the UK a lot recently, with the same meaning. 'Official adoption' is a more neutral way to say basically the same thing.